# Implementing Facebook like content loading

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to implement Facebook like automatic content loading on scrolling in my webpages,how can we easily achieve this?Is there any jquery plugins for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy. First off, you have to note when the element is scrolled to its end. In case of the FB sidebar ticker, or the page as a whole, you will see that when it is scrolled to its end, a loading GIF image is displayed while data is being fetched by AJAX, after which the data is displayed and the GIF image being pushed out of view. To note the moment when the user has scrolled to the bottom, you can do something like :

```
$(element).bind('scroll',function() {
   if ($(this).outerHeight() + $(this).scrollTop() >= $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
   //unbind the 'scroll' event until the data is fetched and displayed
   $(this).unbind('scroll');
   //ajax call to fetch data, display it, and finally rebind the 'scroll' event as a callback function
   }
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your code but how can i practically implement this in my web page?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - To which element we are binding scroll element. Anything particular about that element?

Comment: Well, the element which you want to monitor when the user has scrolled to its end? It can be all `div`s, like `$("div")`, or only one element, `$("#foo")`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use Jquery Waypoints , It will create a event hook when the scroll reaches the bottom of the page , and then ajaxify that according to your usage . [Js Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nVLZA/36/)

Though its using JqueryMobile in the example but its nothing very related to that. Proper usage of this should do the trick . Best of luck !